# XSL copy undesired node value while calling templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have this XML and I need to apply 2 transformations to all a nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <a> V1 </a>
    <b> noo </b>
    <a> v2</a>
    <a> v3</a>
    <b>noo</b>
    <a> v4</a>
    <a> v5</a>
    <a> v6</a>
  </root>
```

These 2 transformations have to be produced sequencially: all "first_transformation" first, then all "second_transformaiton".

I used this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">        
        <xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>   
        <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="t1"/>     
           <xsl:apply-templates mode="t2"/>       
        </xsl:template>   

        <xsl:template match="//a" mode="t1" > 
           <xsl:element name="first_transformation">
               <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>

           </xsl:element>                 
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="//a" mode="t2" > 
            <xsl:element name="second_transformation">
                <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>

            </xsl:element>                 
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you see I use two templates for each transformation, and I call them in a "main" template.

My ouput is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <first_transformation> V1 </first_transformation>
     noo 
    <first_transformation> v2</first_transformation>
    <first_transformation> v3</first_transformation>
    noo
    <first_transformation> v4</first_transformation>
    <first_transformation> v5</first_transformation>
    <first_transformation> v6</first_transformation>
    <second_transformation> V1 </second_transformation>
     noo 
    <second_transformation> v2</second_transformation>
    <second_transformation> v3</second_transformation>
    noo
    <second_transformation> v4</second_transformation>
    <second_transformation> v5</second_transformation>
    <second_transformation> v6</second_transformation>
```

As you see I have these "noo" value from the b nodes that keep beein copied.

Do you know how I can make them disapear from my ouput?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in template rules copy `text()` nodes by default ([link](http://web.uvic.ca/~mholmes/dhoxss2013/handouts/built-in_template_rules.pdf)):

> The built-in rule for any element is to process its child elements and text nodes.

So you have to override this behaviour for each mode.
Therefore add these two templates to your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="t1" /> 
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="t2" />
```

This will remove all superfluous "noo" `text()` nodes.

Comment: Or simply: `<xsl:template match="text()" mode="t1 t2" /> `.

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method='xml' version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>   

<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="t1"/>     
    <xsl:apply-templates select="a" mode="t2"/>       
</xsl:template>   

<xsl:template match="a" mode="t1" > 
    <first_transformation>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </first_transformation>                 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a" mode="t2" > 
    <second_transformation>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </second_transformation>                 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the result is an XML fragment, because it has not root element.